# Getting an injected object using CDI Produces

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi

I have a class (OmeletteMaker) that contains an injected field (Vegetable). I would like to write a producer that instantiates an injected object of this class. If I use 'new', the result will not use injection. If I try to use a WeldContainer, I get an exception, since OmeletteMaker is @Alternative. Is there a third way to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
@Alternative
public class OmeletteMaker implements EggMaker {
    @Inject
    Vegetable vegetable;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Omelette: " + vegetable;
    }
}
```

a vegetable for injection:

```
public class Tomato implements Vegetable {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tomato";
    }

}
```

main file

```
public class CafeteriaMainApp {
    public static WeldContainer container = new Weld().initialize();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Restaurant restaurant = (Restaurant) container.instance().select(Restaurant.class).get();
        System.out.println(restaurant);

    }

    @Produces
    public EggMaker eggMakerGenerator() {
         return new OmeletteMaker();
    }


}
```

The result I get is "Restaurant: Omelette: null", While I'd like to get "Restaurant: Omelette: Tomato"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide OmeletteMaker yourself, its fields will not be injected by the CDI container. To use `@Alternative`, don't forget specifying it in the `beans.xml` and let the container instantiate the EggMaker instance:

```
<alternatives>
    <class>your.package.path.OmeletteMaker</class>
</alternatives>
```

If you only want to implement this with Producer method then my answer may be inappropriate. I don't think it is possible (with standard CDI). The docs says: Producer methods provide a way to inject objects that are not beans, objects whose values may vary at runtime, and objects that require custom initialization.

Thanks Kukeltje for pointing to the other CDI question in comment: 
With CDI extensions like Deltaspike, it is possible to inject the fields into an object created with `new`, simply with `BeanProvider#injectFileds`. I tested this myself:

```java
    @Produces
    public EggMaker eggMakerProducer() {
        EggMaker eggMaker =  new OmeletteMaker();
        BeanProvider.injectFields(eggMaker);
        return eggMaker;
    }
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485661/ (maybe add that to your answer)

Comment: Specifying OmeletteMaker in the beans.xml works, and I can use the container to get the injected object. I wonder if this can be achieved in a Code-only way. In Guice you can simply bind a interface to a concrete class in your java configuration code. What I really want to achieve is a way to let different clients use different classes using code-only configuration. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Shaharg I updated my answer with `BeanProvider#injectFileds` from Apache Deltaspike. Thanks @Kukeltje!